# Nvidia driver for Dell XPS M1330 in XP

Tags: laptop, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I need to run XP, and cannot find a driver that works for this laptop in windows xp.  I have tried quite a few of them, from my google searches, but none work, they all come up and say no proper driver can be found for your hardware.  I have tried to replace the inf files on driver installs but I still get nothing, same error.  Any ideas will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dell does keep the origional system drivers on their site, and will usually post some updates if required.

That said I run the nVidia drivers (from the nVidia's site) on my Dell machine with no problems; do a proper uninstall and find your card and OS on the nVidia site and download the appropriate one, that should work.

Don't do a google search for drivers or system check software you never know what your getting and what is compatible; drivers are easy and difficult to mess up; go to the manufacturer every time and get the quality software then you know what your getting.

Comment: +1 Google is absolutely the wrong place to look for drivers. You have to go to the source - either the original manufacturer of the component or the original manufacturer of the computer.